# App crashes on selecting Spinner in a website openend in a WebView within the App

Tags: android, android-webview, android-alertdialog, tabview, android-spinner

I have a WebView in one of the tabs in TabView. The webView loads a specific url which contains a spinner. The action listener and spinner is triggered from the server side embedded in the url.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
.... 
.... 
webview.loadUrl(locationUrl);
```

My App is developed on Android 2.2. It is working fine in a device with OS 2.2 but When I click the Spinner my app is crashing in a device with OS 2.3.

Below is the log

```
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@406e21e0 is not valid; is your activity running?
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.webkit.WebView$InvokeListBox.run(WebView.java:7583)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: After 2 years, do you have solution? i am experience this problem now.